# How to capture command line options when writting gcc plugin

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I am adding some new features on cpp, I want to write a compiler pass to modify some cpp source codes according to different options.(I use some gcc feature(cilk) , so I think it cannot be done by libclang,clang cannot recognize cilk). Is there any api in gcc can do such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current GCC plugin API does not allow you to extend the preprocessor. However, you can add builtins, pragmas, and function or variable attributes.

You could use `save_decoded_options` and `save_decoded_options_count` from `toplev.h` to get the compiler program arguments. But plugins are expecting `-fplugin-foo-arg-` program arguments (for plugin `foo` ...)

Why do you need these?

Did you consider extending GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a domain specific language to extend GCC)?

Comment: thank you. since I cannot modify cpp source code, modifying AST may be a good idea.I want to add some functions, and replace some function calls.

Comment: by the way, do you know how to convert a gcc ast tree node into source code? thank you.

Comment: You should define what you mean by "converting a GCC AST" to "source code". (This is not really possible, because Gimple is more than plain C, e.g. because it handles exceptions and OpenMP).

Comment: thank you again. I also want to extract some code from source code to do jit. but gcc seems doesn't support jit, so I have to convert the AST node back to source code, and call llvm to compile it.

Comment: Also, I come across a problem, I call some functions defined in gcc's head file, such as walk_tree_1, but when gcc load the plugin, it complains it cannot find symbols. I recompile gcc with many options such as --enable-plugin..., but the problem still exists. have you ever come across such problem?